# R: subsetting data frame by both certain column names (as a variable) and field values

Tags: r, subset

I have list of names and I have a data frame with colnames that match sometimes the names in the list. Now I want to subset the data frame based on two criteria: the colnames (as a variable) in the list and the values of the fields in those columns.

I tried it this way:

```
  names.list <- c("name1", "name2" , "name5")
   names <- as.data.frame(names.list)
   df <- *dataframe with colnames "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", etc.*

   for (i in 1:nrow(names)){
   name <- names[i,1]
   df <- subset(df, name > 1.5)
   }
```

I know this is the wrong way, but I haven't figured out yet to do it properly. Does anyone know how to do this?

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the old-fashioned `[` and `[[` operators:

```
name <- "name1"
df[df[[name]] > 1.5, ]
(etc)
```

Comment: Thanks! like this? 
names.list <- c("name1", "name2" , "name5")
   names <- as.data.frame(names.list)
   df <- *dataframe with colnames "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", etc.*

   for (i in 1:nrow(names)){
   name <- names[i,1]
   df[df[[name]] > 1.5, ]
   }
somewhow this doesnt'seem to work either.

Comment: I forgot to code it like this: df <- df[df[[name]] > 1.5, ]
Your solution works! thank you very much!